# How to "extract" type parameter to instantiate another class

Tags: scala, type-inference, type-parameter, scala-generics

The following Scala code works:

```
object ReducerTestMain extends App {

  type MapOutput = KeyVal[String, Int]

  def mapFun(s:String): MapOutput = KeyVal(s, 1)

  val red = new ReducerComponent[String, Int]((a: Int, b: Int) => a + b)

  val data = List[String]("a", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b")

  data foreach {s => red(mapFun(s))}
  println(red.mem)
  // OUTPUT: Map(a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 2)
}

class ReducerComponent[K, V](f: (V, V) => V) {
  var mem = Map[K, V]()

  def apply(kv: KeyVal[K, V]) = {
    val KeyVal(k, v) = kv
    mem += (k -> (if (mem contains k) f(mem(k), v) else v))
  }
}

case class KeyVal[K, V](key: K, value:V)
```

My problem is I would like to instantiate `ReducerComponent` like this:

```
val red = new ReducerComponent[MapOutput, Int]((a: Int, b: Int) => a + b)
```

or even better:

```
val red = new ReducerComponent[MapOutput](_ + _)
```

That means a lot of things:

1. I would like to type-check that `MapOutput` is of the type `KeyVal[K, C]`,
2. I want to type-check that `C` is the same type used in `f`,
3. I also need to "extract" `K` in order to instantiate `mem`, and type-check parameters from `apply`.

Is it a lot to ask? :) I wanted to write something like

```
class ReducerComponent[KeyVal[K,V]](f: (V, V) => V) {...}
```

By the time I will instantiate `ReducerComponent` all I have is `f` and `MapOutput`, so inferring V is OK. But then I only have `KeyVal[K,V]` as a type parameter from a class, which can be different from `KeyVal[_,_]`.

I know what I'm asking is probably crazy if you understand how type inference works, but I don't! And I don't even know what would be a good way to proceed --- apart from making explicit type declarations all the way up in my high-level code. Should I just change all the architecture?

Answer (score 5):

Just write a simple factory:

```
case class RC[M <: KeyVal[_, _]](){
   def apply[K,V](f: (V,V) => V)(implicit ev: KeyVal[K,V] =:= M) = new ReducerComponent[K,V](f)
}

def plus(x: Double, y: Double) = x + y

scala> RC[KeyVal[Int, Double]].apply(plus)
res12: ReducerComponent[Int,Double] = ReducerComponent@7229d116

scala> RC[KeyVal[Int, Double]]()(plus)
res16: ReducerComponent[Int,Double] = ReducerComponent@389f65fe
```

As you can see, `ReducerComponent` has appropriate type. Implicit evidence is used here to catch `K` and `V` from your `M <: KeyVal[_, _]`.

P.S. The version above requires to specify parameter types explicitly for your `f`, like `(_: Double) + (_: Double)`. If you want to avoid this:

```
case class RC[M <: KeyVal[_, _]](){
   def factory[K,V](implicit ev: KeyVal[K,V] =:= M) = new {
      def apply(f: (V,V) => V) = new ReducerComponent[K,V](f)
   }
}

scala> RC[KeyVal[Int, Double]].factory.apply(_ + _)
res5: ReducerComponent[Int,Double] = ReducerComponent@3dc04400 


scala> val f = RC[KeyVal[Int, Double]].factory
f: AnyRef{def apply(f: (Double, Double) => Double): ReducerComponent[Int,Double]} = RC$$anon$1@19388ff6

scala> f(_ + _)
res13: ReducerComponent[Int,Double] = ReducerComponent@24d8ae83
```

Update. If you want to generelize keyval - use type function:

```
type KV[K,V] = KeyVal[K,V] //may be anything, may implement `type KV[K,V]` from some supertrait

case class RC[M <: KV[_, _]](){   
  def factory[K,V](implicit ev: KV[K,V] =:= M) = new {
    def apply(f: (V,V) => V) = new ReducerComponent[K,V](f)
  }
}
```

But keep in mind that `apply` from your question still takes `KeyVal[K,V]`.

You can also pass `KV` into some class:

```
class Builder[KV[_,_]] {
  case class RC[M <: KV[_, _]](){   
    def factory[K,V](implicit ev: KV[K,V] =:= M) = new {
      def apply(f: (V,V) => V) = new ReducerComponent[K,V](f)
    }
  }
}

scala> val b = new Builder[KeyVal]
scala> val f = b.RC[KeyVal[Int, Double]].factory
scala> f(_ + _)
res2: ReducerComponent[Int,Double] = ReducerComponent@54d9c993
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't think of using evidences that way. +1 since it doesn't need type members (which tend to confuse people).

Comment: Actually i have compilation error `type arguments [A$A292.this.MapOutput] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [M <: Map[_, _]]`

Comment: @dk14 the very last factory version worked. Nice job!

Comment: OK, that seems promising, but in my actual problem what I have is `object ReducerTest[MapOutput] { def buildReducer(f)...}`, and this `MapOutput` can be something different from `KeyVal[_,_]`. I want the `buildReducer` method to fail in this case, but I should still be able to create the `ReducerTest` object. Scala is apparently failing compilation saying it can't prove `MapOutput =:= KeyVal` always.

Comment: I couldn't adapt it to my actual problem. Here is what I have,

    `class MyBuilder[A](mystate:Sometype) {
      def buildMapper[B](f: A=>B)=MyBuilder[B](Map(f)::state);
      def buildReducer[V](f: (V,V)=>V)=MyBuilder[V](Red(f)::state);
    }`

The "state" is a type-checked chain of workers. It works great for the `buildMapper`, the class type argument stores the last function return type. But for the reducer A should hold some KeyVal[K,V]. The `implicit` works with specific types, but I couldn't get the type function thing working... I should perhaps create two sister Builder classes?

Comment: @dividebyzero if `A` in `buildMapper` and `A` needed for `buildReducer` are actually different `A`s - then yes, you may pass `KV` right into your builder: `class ReducerBuilder[KV[_, _]] {...}`

Comment: @dividebyzero I've added that option to the answer

Answer (score 4):

You will need path-dependent types for this. I recommend the following:

First, write a trait that has your relevant types as members, so you can access them within definitions:

```
trait KeyValAux {
  type K
  type V
  type KV = KeyVal[K, V]
}
```

Now you can create a factory for `ReducerComponent`:

```
object ReducerComponent {
  def apply[T <: KeyValAux](f: (T#V, T#V) => T#V) =
    new ReducerComponent[T#K, T#V](f)
}
```

Note that here, we can simply access the members of the type. We can't do this for type parameters.

Now, define your `MapOutput` in terms of `KeyValAux` (maybe another name is more appropriate for your use case):

```
type MapOutput = KeyValAux { type K = String; type V = Int }

def mapFun(s:String): MapOutput#KV = KeyVal(s, 1)

val red = ReducerComponent[MapOutput](_ + _)
```

**UPDATE**

As @dk14 mentions in the comments, if you still want the type-parameter syntax, you could do the following:

```
trait OutputSpec[KK, VV] extends KeyValAux {
  type K = KK
  type V = VV
}
```

You can then write:

```
type MapOutput = OutputSpec[String, Int]
```

Alternatively, you can write `OutputSpec` as a type function:

```
type OutputSpec[KK, VV] = KeyValAux { type K = KK; type V = VV }
```

This will not generate an additional unused class.

Comment: it might be better to define `trait KeyValAux[KK, VV] { type K = KK; type V = VV; type KV = KeyVal[K, V] }` to make `MapOutput` definition a bit nicer: `type MapOutput = KeyValAux[String, Int]`

Comment: Then there is no way anymore to write `ReducerComponent.apply`. But we could write a subclass that does this.