# Getting over type parameter bounds error with type checked by TypeTag

Tags: scala, reflection, type-inference, type-erasure

I think I am close to start understanding type erasure and the Scala reflection API. But I'm still in a world of pain...

How do I deal with this problem? I have a class that can take generic functions as arguments, and I need to do different things depending on the type from the function output. I also need to be able to "extract" the types. (This is all related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754283/how-to-extract-type-parameter-to-instantiate-another-class) of mine, which helped me a lot, but still didn't solve my real problem.)

I know I can do the following:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object ReflectiveMysteryA extends App {

  def stupidFunc[A: TypeTag](arg: List[A]) = typeOf[A] match {
    case t if t =:= typeOf[List[String]] =>
      println("its a list of list of string")
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Set[Int]] =>
      println("its a list of set of int")
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Set[Long]] =>
      println("its a list of set of Long")
    case _ =>
      println("WTF")
  }

  stupidFunc(List(List("a", "bc"), List("b", "def")))
  stupidFunc(List(Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3, 4)))
  stupidFunc(List(Set(0L, 432L), Set(321L)))
  stupidFunc(List(Set("a", "bc", "def")))
  // stupidFunc(Set(Set("a", "bc", "def")))  // Doesn't compile, "type mismatch"
}
// its a list of list of string
// its a list of set of int
// its a list of set of Long
// WTF
```

This is all good good, we test the type using `TypeTag` and then we do the corresponding stuff. But it only works as long as you don't really need to be sure about that type you tested...

For instance, now I have a function like this, with type parameter bounds and an implicit argument that is used to "extract" type B from type LSB from the function argument:

```
object ReflectiveMysteryB extends App {

  def specialFunc[LSB <: List[Set[_]], B: TypeTag](vv: LSB)(implicit ev: List[Set[B]] =:= LSB) = {
    typeOf[B] match {
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] =>
        println("list of set of int")
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Long] =>
        println("list of set of long")
    }
  }

  specialFunc(List(Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3, 4)))
  specialFunc(List(Set(0L, 432L), Set(321L)))
  // specialFunc(List(List("a", "bc"), List("b", "def"))) // Doesn't compile, "type parameter bounds"
}
// list of set of int
// list of set of long
```

This is working fine too. The problem happens when I try to compose the two things:

```
object ReflectiveMysteryC extends App {

  def stupiderFunc[A: TypeTag](arg: List[A]) = typeOf[A] match {
    case t if t =:= typeOf[List[String]] =>
      println("its a list of list of string")
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Set[Int]] =>
      specialFunc(arg)
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Set[Long]] =>
      specialFunc(arg)
    case _ =>
      println("WTF")
  }

  def specialFunc[LSB <: List[Set[_]], B: TypeTag](vv: LSB)(implicit ev: List[Set[B]] =:= LSB) = {
    typeOf[B] match {
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] =>
        println("list of set of int")
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Long] =>
        println("list of set of long")
    }
  }

  stupiderFunc(List(List("a", "bc"), List("b", "def")))
  stupiderFunc(List(Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3, 4)))
  stupiderFunc(List(Set(0L, 432L), Set(321L)))
  stupiderFunc(List(Set("a", "bc", "def")))
}
```

That won't compile

```
Error:(45, 7) inferred type arguments [List[A],Nothing] do not conform to method specialFunc's type parameter bounds [LSB <: List[Set[_]],B]
      specialFunc(arg)
      ^
Error:(45, 19) type mismatch;
 found   : List[A]
 required: LSB
      specialFunc(arg)
                  ^
Error:(45, 18) Cannot prove that List[Set[B]] =:= LSB.
      specialFunc(arg)
                 ^
Error:(47, 7) inferred type arguments [List[A],Nothing] do not conform to method specialFunc's type parameter bounds [LSB <: List[Set[_]],B]
      specialFunc(arg)
      ^
Error:(47, 19) type mismatch;
 found   : List[A]
 required: LSB
      specialFunc(arg)
                  ^
Error:(47, 18) Cannot prove that List[Set[B]] =:= LSB.
      specialFunc(arg)
                 ^
```

To make it work, we could do the following:

```
object ReflectiveMysteryD extends App {

  def stupiderFunc[A: TypeTag](arg: List[A]) = typeOf[A] match {
    case t if t =:= typeOf[List[String]] =>
      println("its a list of list of string")
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Set[Int]] =>
      specialFunc(arg.asInstanceOf[List[Set[Int]]])
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Set[Long]] =>
      specialFunc(arg.asInstanceOf[List[Set[Long]]])
    case _ =>
      println("WTF")
  }

  def specialFunc[B: TypeTag](vv: List[Set[B]]) = {
    typeOf[B] match {
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] =>
        println("list of set of int")
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Long] =>
        println("list of set of long")
    }
  }

  stupiderFunc(List(List("a", "bc"), List("b", "def")))
  stupiderFunc(List(Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3, 4)))
  stupiderFunc(List(Set(0L, 432L), Set(321L)))
  stupiderFunc(List(Set("a", "bc", "def")))
}
// its a list of list of string
// list of set of int
// list of set of long
// WTF
```

But now my problem is: How can I match the general case of `List[Set[_]]` in `stupiderFunc` in order to apply `specialFunc` to `arg` without having to list all the specific `Int` or `Long` types? Is there a way to use `asInstanceOf` without fixing the inner type parameter? Or is there a way to fix the `implicit` approach so it is able to figure out that `args` actually conforms to the expected type by the time we are calling `specialFunc` inside the `match`?

Is this a problem I might be using macros to solve? How should I proceed in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want:

```
object NotAnyMoreMysteryD extends App {

  def stupiderFunc[A: TypeTag, Z: TypeTag, T[_]](arg: List[A])(implicit ev: A =:= T[Z]) = typeOf[A] match {
    case t if t <:< typeOf[List[_]] =>
      println("its a list of list of string")
    case t if t <:< typeOf[Set[_]] =>
      specialFunc(arg.asInstanceOf[List[Set[Z]]])
    case _ =>
      println("WTF")
  }

  def specialFunc[B: TypeTag](vv: List[Set[B]]) = {
    typeOf[B] match {
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] =>
        println("list of set of int")
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Long] =>
        println("list of set of long")
    }
  }

  stupiderFunc(List(List("a", "bc"), List("b", "def")))
  stupiderFunc(List(Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3, 4)))
  stupiderFunc(List(Set(0L, 432L), Set(321L)))
  stupiderFunc(List(Set("a", "bc", "def")))
}
```

Alternative:

```
def stupiderFunc[A[Z], Z: TypeTag](arg: List[A[Z]])(implicit tag: TypeTag[A[Z]]) = typeOf[A[Z]] match {
    case t if t <:< typeOf[List[_]] =>
      println("its a list of list of string")
    case t if t <:< typeOf[Set[_]] =>
      specialFunc(arg.asInstanceOf[List[Set[Z]]])
    case _ =>
      println("WTF")
}
```

Results:

```
scala>  stupiderFunc(List(List("a", "bc"), List("b", "def")))
its a list of list of string

scala> stupiderFunc(List(Set(1, 2), Set(2, 3, 4)))
list of set of int

scala> stupiderFunc(List(Set(0L, 432L), Set(321L)))
list of set of long

scala> stupiderFunc(List(Set("a", "bc", "def")))
scala.MatchError
```

Comment: OK, that was great, but I just managed to create another example that is not exactly what I needed. I have cases where `T` can be a container, or not. In that case `T[Z]` doesn't makes sense. How do you deal with that? I have a `case t if t =:= Function[X, Tuple[_,_]]`, and then a `case _`, and then I need to cast to call a specific function for that special type (a function that returns a tuple).

Comment: I would deal with that by dividing it into two functions. first-level - takes parameter without container and if it's containner - then call a secondone  that takes container